# Cannot display column headers using acts_as_xlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I'm using the acts_as_xlsx gem to produce excel reports in rails. I followed the examples to create column headers by adding them to my en.yml file and including :i18n => true in my model, but the row is blank. All the other data is showing up correctly.

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @claims = Claim.all

  respond_to do | format |
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @claims }
    format.xlsx {

    xlsx_package = Claim.to_xlsx :name => "Claims", 
                               :header_style => {:bg_color => "377", 
                               :fg_color => "FF",  
                               :sz => 16, 
                               :alignment => { :horizontal => :center }}
    begin
      temp = Tempfile.new("claims.xlsx")
      xlsx_package.serialize temp.path
      send_data xlsx_package.to_stream.read, :filename => 'claims.xlsx', :type=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ensure
      temp.close
      temp.unlink
    end
  }  
  end
end
```

**Model:**

```
acts_as_xlsx :columns => [:id, :business_unit_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :claim_number], :i18n => true
```

**En.yml:**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      claims: Claims
      claim:
        id: "Claim Id"
        business_unit_id: "Business Unit"
        created_at: "Created at"
        updated_at: "Updated at"
        claim_number: "Claim Number"
```

Comment: Ok, I realized the issue is with preview on a Mac (since I don't have excel). When I uploaded the doc to google drive, I saw the text in the column header (note: I also removed :fg_color => "FF" so my font wasn't white on a yellow background). Even with those changes, I'm still not sure why I can see the data in other rows but not in the column header row using preview. But the data is populating the field correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working is that the en.yml file you are using a plural form of claims where you should use claim.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    claim:
      id: "Claim Id "
      business_unit_id: "Business Unit "
      created_at: "Created at "
      updated_at: "Updated at "
      claim_number: "Claim Number "
```

I think the switch that is supposed to be used for i8n is actually "activerecord.attributes", based off of the latest documentation.

```
:i18n => "activerecord.attributes"
```

On a side note, I believe you need to add a space after the title otherwise your titles displayed within your form errors will not be spaced correctly.